# 'RuntimeError: route set not finalized' when calling Rails.application.routes.generate() or Rails.application.routes.recognize_path()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I use the `Rails.application.routes.generate()` and `Rails.application.routes.recognize_path()` in my application to disassemble and generate URLs using the Rails routing table. I never had a problem with this using the Rails 2.3.x series but since Rails 3 (specifically 3.1.3) I've been getting the following error when invoking these commands

`RuntimeError: route set not finalized`

Two questions :

- Why? Am I getting this - my application is up and running and handling other requests. Why are the routes not finalized by now?
- To solve this error I call Rails.application.routes.finalize! before invoking either of these methods as it seems to work. Are there any implications to doing this?

Comment: where you use this method in your code ?

Comment: @shingara In a model. Should that make a difference?

Comment: yes because you need use something else.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 3, you don't use this technic. You need include `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` after you can use your named_route

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def my_own_url
    user_url(self)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks shingara. So to mimic generate() I can use - Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for("/orders/1".merge(:only_path => true))

Comment: But how do I mimic Rails.application.routes.recognize_path() so that I can take a URL such as "/orders/1" and split it into its :controller, :action and :id ?