# Ruby on Rails - Map URL to a controller, method, and parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url-routing, rails-console

I know that the file routes.rb in a Rails application maps a URL to a controller, a method, and a set of parameters in the params hash. This is complicated somewhat by "resources", nested resources, and non-RESTful routes.

Is there a way to run a command on the rails console to map a URL and figure out exactly which controller, which method, which http method(s), and the exact value of a parameter hash from a given URL?

Is it then possible to then run the controller method with the parameters hash on the rails console and get the output of the controller sent to STDOUT? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Try these

```
Rails.application.routes.named_routes.each{|p,s| puts p,s} 
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.my_path_helper   # To get url for a path helper
```

or

```
route = Rails.application.routes
route.recognize_path "/poweruser/3"           # will give you result exactly you wanted
```

Comment: The second one was an OK answer. But I sometimes get an error (RuntimeError route set not finalized). This page at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9291366/runtimeerror-route-set-not-finalized-when-calling-rails-application-routes-ge suggests that this technique is not good for Rails 3. Also...this technique doesn't work for routes which only work with a HTTP POST.

Comment: well I commonly used the first one commands to filter and lookup the routes, their helpers etc.

Answer (score 1):

try it with running

```
bundle exec rake routes
```

See [Determine if path exists as route in Rails controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273715/determine-if-path-exists-as-route-in-rails-controller)

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path
```

Comment: I know about this. What I was looking for was something in particular. For example if I could run a command such as "route '/poweruser/3'", it might give me something like "{:controller=>"poweruser, :params=>{:id=>3} }" as a return value (a hash of hashes).